# How to make the li a direct selection of the ul , while maintaining the SCSS syntax?

Tags: html, css, sass

I have just started using scss recently ,  Now i often write code like this:

```
.site-internal-navigation {
    &:after,
    &:before {
        display: none;
    }
    display: flex;
    align-items:center;
    justify-content:space-between;


    .site-nav-links-list {
        li {
            display: inline-block;
        }
    }
}
```

Overall  i really like scss, not much differrent from css. Now what do i do whant to code a menu that has multiple nested `li's` and `ul's`

For example in the below code:

```
ul.site-nav-links-list {
    li {
        display: inline-block;
    }
}
```

I would actually like to make the `li` selection a direct child of the `ul` , but at the same time maintaining the above syntax, how do i do this ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding an `>`, it refers to the "direct child"

```
ul.site-nav-links-list {
    >li {
        display: inline-block;
    }
}
```